# Running web application locally in Eclipse returns HTTP status code 500

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, tomcat

The situation is that I'm running a local DXA webapp in Eclipse that should communicate with the CD server so I can test a website. The problem is that I can't get past the HTTP status code of 500 (Internal Server Error).

I know that the webapp runs successfully on the server-side because I can browse the site on my PC using the server's domain/IP. So, in my understanding, the issue is that the locally-hosted webapp is unable to get the data it needs to function or unable to communicate with one/more of the SDL microservices. I have allowed the discovery service's port on the server through the firewall.

**Frameworks**:
SDL Web 8.5, DXA 2.0 Java

**Server:** 
Apache Tomcat 8.5.34

When trying to run the webapp locally I am getting the below exception for all requests.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Unable to perform action
    at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.performAction(DefaultODataClient.java:93)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ContentClient.lambda$performAction$7(ContentClient.java:273)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ClientRequestRetrySupporter$RetryBlock.execute(ClientRequestRetrySupporter.java:60)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ClientRequestRetrySupporter.runWithRetry(ClientRequestRetrySupporter.java:27)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ContentClient.performAction(ContentClient.java:272)
    at com.sdl.web.ambient.client.AmbientClientFilter.performADFAction(AmbientClientFilter.java:63)
    at com.sdl.web.ambient.client.AmbientClientFilter.processStartEvents(AmbientClientFilter.java:97)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Are the other service ports open too? Discovery will only send back the connection details for the other services, it will not proxy the connections.

Comment: Maybe helpful to debug java  DXA setup in eclipse  http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/using-and-debugging-dxa-java-with-web-8-5-on-amazon